# Prove: $U$ Is A Subspace Of $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $V=\mathbb{R}_3[x]$ and let the subgroup 
>   $U=\{p(x)\in V: p(x)=xp'(x)\}$
>
> Prove: $U$ is a subspace of $V$

Let $p(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ therefore $p'(x)=3a_3x^2+2a_2x+a_1$ so $xp'(x)=3a_3x^3+2a_2x^2+a_1x$

So $U$ is all $p(x)$ s.t $$a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=3a_3x^3+2a_2x^2+a_1x$$

Or  $$a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0-3a_3x^3-2a_2x^2-a_1x=0\iff (a_3-3a_3)x^3+(a_2-2a_2)x^2+a_0=0$$

So $-2a_3=0 \iff a_30$ , $-a_2=0 \iff a_2= 0$, $a_1=0$

So $U=\{p(x)\in V: p(x)=\alpha x\}$

1.$(0,0,0,0)\in U$

2. Let $\gamma\in F$ $\alpha x, \beta x\in U$

$$\alpha x+\gamma \cdot \beta x=(\alpha+\gamma\cdot \beta)x\in U$$

So $U$ is a subspace.

Is this valid?

Comment: It looks fine to me...nice! Just two lines before point 1., at the right end it must be, I believe, $\;a_0=0\;$ , and in the middle there $\;a_3=0\;$

Comment: A agree with @DonAntonio, but there *is* a far simpler way to go: show that if $p$ is any polynomial satisfying $p(x) = xp'(x)$, then a constant multiple $s(x) = c p(x)$ also satisfies $s(x) = x s'(x)$. You needn't use anything except rules for derivatives (i.e., no need to write out explicit polynomials). Then suppose that $q$ also satisfies $q(x) = x q'(x)$ and show that $r = p + q$ must satisfy $r(x) = x r'(x)$. At that point, you've shown that $U$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, and is therefore a subspace.

Comment: There's a reason this is a "better" way: If $V$ is any vector space of differentiable functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, and $U$ is the subset consisting of those for which $f'(x) = x f(x)$, then this proof shows that $U$ is a subspace, without any further knowledge of what the elements of $U$ must look like.