# Proof verification: proof that $U=\{p(x)\in V \mid p(x)=x\cdot p'(x)\}$ is a subspace of $V=\Bbb R_{3}[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials

So I am currently working on an **alternative proof** to [Prove: $U$ Is A Subspace Of $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571816/prove-u-is-a-subspace-of-mathbbr-3x). Here is what I have so far:

$\forall p(x)\in U:$

$p(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3=bx+2cx^2+3dx^3=x\cdot p'(x)$

Lets put this in a matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&1&2&3\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1&-2\\0&1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore,

$$U=\{a+2b+x(-2a-3b)+x^2(a)+x^3(b)\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\}=\operatorname{span}\{1-2x + x^2, 2-3x+x^3\}$$

So according to the definition of $\operatorname{span},$ $U$ is a subspace.

Comment: I've no idea what and/or how you did "put this in a matrix" ....what did you REALLY do and what did you put there?

Comment: Subtract both sides by $bx$ and then set both sides equal to $-bx$. then set the columns to the 1's place, $x$'s place, $x^2$'s place, $x^3$'s place

Comment: I think you *should* put all this in your post...and I still don't understand what you did and how that helps you solve.

Comment: I think DonAntonio was suggesting that the step when you put things into a matrix should really be you solving equations on the coefficients simultaneously. However your matrix method seems not to work. Have you checked whether the vectors you say span $U$ are even in $U$?

Comment: @gvv I see that my result cannot possibly be correct. looks like I need to rethink this a bit

Comment: @CluelessButCurious, maybe think more about when two polynomials are equal?

Comment: Hint: if you’re going to “put this in a matrix,” you need to find a matrix that represents the equation $p(x)-xp'(x)=0$.

Comment: Typically we first prove $U$ to be a subspace, then we would apply the tool of matrices. You cannot claim that $U$ is spanned by some polynomials that easily. Maybe the direct verification of definition would be the common yet widely accepted proof.

Comment: It’s always a good idea to check your answer. You’ve calculated that $U=\operatorname{span}\{1-2x+x^2,2-3x+x^3\}$, but does either of those polynomials satisfy the defining equation of $U$?